# How the pixel value (RGB) actually displayed on screen

Tags: opencv

I actually want to understand the actual working of the openCV inbuilt functions: imread() and imshow()
How the actual colour of the image displayed on the screen are actually converted into RGB value.
How the hex value(0,255) represent a colour
Basically i want to know the relation between physical thing and the machine thing.

Comment: This is a very good question. I also care about the answer.

Comment: Can anyone tell how to locate the source code of cv2.imread(). This will also help.

Comment: Read about [Color Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory). `imread` just used `libpng`, `libjpeg`, etc... to load PNG, JPG images... nothing fancy about that.

Comment: I read the article Colour Theory. It still doesn't clarify my doubt of numerical representation of colour.

Comment: can you clarify your question? Can you give examples what you mean by physical thing and machine thing etc?

Comment: Yeah! Machines read the image in the form of RGB value of a pixel say [30,244,255] (one of the representations) but originally we see colours on the screen when the .jpeg image is displayed.

Comment: in OpenCV imread function reads a jpeg image in the form of array of RGB values. How? From this point this question came

Comment: I got the answer......its actually sensor array in the cameras that provides digital values (RGB) to the image....thats how we get numeric pixel values

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
```

include above line in your code, it has cv2.imread() function. 
Second argument is a flag which specifies the way image should be read.

```
cv2.IMREAD_COLOR : Loads a color image. Any transparency of image will be neglected. It is the default flag.
cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE : Loads image in grayscale mode
cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED : Loads image as such including alpha channel

Note : Instead of these three flags, you can simply pass integers 1, 0 or -1 respectively.
```

For more details visit this [link1](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2013/06/load-display-image.html) and [link2](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html).

Comment: I wanna know how imread convertes a .jpg picture into pixel values. Can you provide me the source code of imread()